# Why table,tr,td,etc is not part of the default whitelist elements for the new sanitize html method in version 3.4.1 of bootstrap-sass gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass, bootstrap-popover

I was checking out the changes of the new version (3.4.1) of bootstrap-sass gem, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass, because my popover that rendered a table inside stopped working, and was wondering why the tags related to table as table itself, tr, td, th, are not part of the default whitelist used to sanitize the html.

Is there any problem related to sanitize these tags that can cause security issues?

The default whitelist elements is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer